# ListBox not posting to MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, listbox

I have a form which have some text Area's and ListBox. All the other fields in the form are being posted to controller but not ListBox?

Here is Razor code:

```
 <form method="post" action="/Admin/AddPost">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="BlogTitle" placeholder="Title" value="@Model.BlogTitle" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Image</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="BlogImage" value="@Model.BlogImage" placeholder="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea name="BlogDescription">@Model.BlogDescription</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tags</label>
        @Html.ListBox("Tags", Model.Tags, new { @class = "form-control", @name = "Tags", @multiple = "multiple" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Here is GET and POST from controller:

```
 public ActionResult AddPost()
    {
        var model = new BlogModel
        {
            BlogTitle = string.Empty,
            BlogDescription = string.Empty,
            BlogImage = string.Empty,
            Tags = new TagQueries().GetAllTags().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.TagName,
                Value = x.TagId.ToString(),
                Selected = false
            })
        };
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPost(BlogModel model)
    {
        TransferBlogDetailsToDbModel addToDb = new TransferBlogDetailsToDbModel();
        if (ModelState.IsValid && model != null)
        {
            try
            {
                addToDb.TransferBlogDetails(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid data,Please try again");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is the Model:

```
public class BlogModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Blog Title is required")]
    public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Blog description is required")]
    public string BlogDescription { get; set; }
    public string BlogImage { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property `Tags` is typeof `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and you cannot bind a `<select multiple>` to a collection of complex objects. A `<select>` posts back an array of simple values (the values of the selected options).

Your model needs a property to bind to, say

```
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedTags { get; set; }
```

assuming that the `TagId` of `Tag` is typeof `int`. Then the code in the view is

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags , Model.Tags, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Side notes:

1. Do not use `new { @name = "..." }` - fortunately it does nothing,
   and never attempt to override the `name` attribute generated by
   the `HtmlHelper` methods
2. Do not use `new { @multiple = "multiple" }` - the `ListBox()` and
   `ListBoxFor()` methods already generate that
3. Use the `TextBoxFor() and`TextAreaFor()` methods to generate your
   other form controls so that you get correct 2-way model binding
4. Remove the `Selected = false` code in the `SelectListItem`
   constructor (not only is it false by default, the value is ignored
   anyway - its the value of `SelectedTags` which determines what is
   selected)

Answer (score 1):

Use the IEnumerable only to populate the box and add another property to hold the list of selected items values from ListBox, as follow:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SelectedTags { get; set; }
```

Note: The SelectedTags filling will depend on the way of your SelectListItem was been created. If the SelectListItem.Value is set, the SelectedTags will contains these values, otherwise SelectedTags will fill out with the value of SelectedListItem.Text property.